# Comparable и Comparator

Tags: java, compare

Есть класс со сгенерированным кодом в нем поля:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
    String name;
    Character sex;
    int age;
    int course;
    double avgGrade;
```

Имплементировал `Comparable` для сортировки по возрасту и хочу написать `Comparator` для сортировки допустим по полу.

```
class StudentSexComparator implements Comparator<Student>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Student st1, Student st2) {
        return st1.sex.compareTo(st2.sex);
    }
```

1. Если использовать примитив (char) то сравнивать вообще не дает. Это значит что поля по которым сравниваем должен быть обязательно *Оберткой*?
2. Можете подсказать почему в StudentSexComparator метод compare не дает возможности пользоваться геттерами и так ли критично если в этом случает обращаться к полям напрямую?

Comment: `char sex; sex.compareTo` не имеет смысла. `sex` не объект в этом случае, следовательно не может иметь методы.

Comment: Покажите геттеры про которые говорите. Если они возвращают примитивы - см. пункт первый.

Comment: См. [Character.compare(char x, char y)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#compare-char-char-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на первый вопрос уже дал в комментариях @Stanislav Volodarskiy: если поле содержит примитивное значение `char`, у такого типа не может быть метода `compareTo`, и *при собственной реализации* компаратора нужно будет пользоваться методом `Character::compare(char a, char b)`.

Геттерами также никто не запрещает пользоваться:

```java
@Getter
public class Student {
    private Character sex;
 // ...
}

class StudentSexComparator implements Comparator<Student>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Student st1, Student st2) {
        return st1.getSex().compareTo(st2.getSex());          // для Character
//      return Character.compare(st1.getSex(), st2.getSex()); // для char
    }
}
```

---

Отвечая на второй вопрос по поводу геттеров.  Отдельный класс для компаратора с деталями реализации можно вообще пропустить при использовании ссылок на соответствующий геттер класса `Student`:

```java
Comparator<Student> bySex = Comparator.comparing(Student::getSex);
```

Аналогично, можно воспользоваться методом, сравнивающий примитив:

```java
Comparator<Student> bySexPrim = Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getSex);
```

В зависимости от того, как определён тип, возвращаемый геттером (`char` или `Character`), автоматически будет применяться boxing/unboxing.